# Is there a JSHint or JSLint plugin for IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, jslint, jshint

I know IntelliJ 11 has added support for JSLint, but is there a plugin for older versions that will validate js files against either JSLint or JSHint?  Ideally one that will inspect the code as it is typed rather than having to be run separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try IntelliJ IDEA [11.1 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP), it supports both JSLint and JSHint:

[image: jshint]

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for something for version 10, as I'm not yet able to upgrade.  I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, tested with InteliJ IDEA 10.5.4 and it works.
You can find step by step instructions at: http://derekscrib.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/jslint-external-tool-for-intellij/

Comment: @Dilpa with IntelliJ 13 JSHint and JSLint are already included see http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/05/lint-your-javascript-with-jslintjshint-in-real-time/ for where you can find them and http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/jslint.html for JSLint docs